# how to create custom events in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to create my own event in vb.net .

I need an event for WindowState = Normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`SizeChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged.aspx) event to monitor changes to `WindowState`. Then you can expose your own custom event that is raised when it changes:

```
Public Event WindowStateChanged As EventHandler
Private currentWindowsState As FormWindowState

Protected Overrides Sub OnSizeChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnSizeChanged(e)
    If WindowState <> currentWindowsState Then
        currentWindowsState = WindowState
        OnWindowStateChanged(EventArgs.Empty)
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub OnWindowStateChanged(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent WindowStateChanged(Me, e)
End Sub
```

This sample will raise the `WindowStateChanged` event whenever it changes, regardless of from what state and to what state. You can easily add conditions to raise it only for certain states.